# biblatex-verbose: Comma after editor instead of period

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

The period after “Editor” should be a comma. I tracked down the `byeditor+others` bibmacro, but couldn’t figure out what I needed to change. A `\DeclareFieldFormat`, which has helped with punctuation in other cases, didn’t help either.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{foo,
    author = {Author},
    title = {Title},
    booktitle = {Booktitle},
    editor = {Editor},
    location = {Location},
    year = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{foo}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if the following is the best method, but substituting `\newunit` with `\addcomma` in the definition of `byeditor+others` works.

Add

```
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \addcomma}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
```

to your preamble.

So, modifying your MWE to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{foo,
    author = {Author},
    title = {Title},
    booktitle = {Booktitle},
    editor = {Editor},
    location = {Location},
    year = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \addcomma}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{foo}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]